# Runtime Error during ionic serve

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

Can anyone help me with following error

**Error: Cannot find module "ionic-angular/components/app/app-constants"**

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic Native: 2.2.11
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.7
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 6.10.2
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

I have already reinstalled node modules couple of times but it didn't seems to fixed the issue.

Comment: add your app.module.ts and app-constants file

Comment: @suraj I dont have app-constants file..also its referring to app-constants file inside ionic-angular/components/app, I have checked for app-constants its not there as well

Comment: ah.. sorry my bad.. are you referring anything like that?

Comment: no,i guess its getting referred internally

Comment: Upgrade your ionic version from rc4 to 3.1.0. The app scripts is 1.3.7 which only supports latest version. Update everything, basically.

Comment: @misha130 updated ionic version now i am getting another error while ionic serve.                                                                                           [ERROR] Error occurred while loading plugins. CLI functionality may be limited.
        Checking for CLI updates now...
[ERROR] No updates found after plugin error--please report this issue.

Comment: Look at cli docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent whole day upgrading and downgrading my plugins and nothing resolved the error,so i am going to share what i did just in case it helps anyone.

Cause of the error was exception thrown at the run time from the main.js file which is a build file generated at the run time during ionic serve,and after a bit of looking over the code it happened to be a plugin named **datepicker-ionic2**
was throwing this error.

So i removed the above plugin from my project and built the project again and error was gone.